# @media не работает в Safari iOS

Tags: ios, css3, iphone, safari, media-queries

Уже все перерыл, не могу понять, почему не работают медиа запросы именно в Safari для iOS. В Chrome для iOS, например, все работает прекрасно. На андроид, а также на пк при уменьшении размера окна браузера - работает.
Сайт на bootstrap 4, под wordpress, если это важно.
В head имеется

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="wp-content/themes/adcar/js/css3-mediaqueries.min.js"></script>
```

Медиа запросы выглядят так

```
<style>
 @media (max-width: 767px)
 @media (max-width: 991px)
</style>
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: А можно более подробный пример стилей? или ссылку на страницу/пример кода на codepen/jsfiddle или прямо тут.

Comment: При этом встроенные в bootstrap.css @media запросы работают?
Не может быть такого, что ваш файл стилей подключен до других и стандартные bootstrap'ные стили перетирают те, что написали вы?
Сложно не видя код что-то подсказать, `css3-mediaqueries.js` по идее глюков таких не должна добавить, но можно попробовать отключить её на время и посмотреть сохранится ли баг на iOs.

Comment: Я его подключил в попытках исправить ситуацию, поэтому отключение не поможет.

Comment: Через веб-инспектор с iOs есть возможность посмотреть что там Safari за стили видит? Вы на устройстве проверяете верстку?

Comment: Нет, не проверял, сейчас скачаю, посмотрю!

Comment: В смысле сейчас скачаю - посмотрю? С macos Safari можно по проводу подключиться к iPhone и провести отладку через встроенный веб инспектор iOs Safari. Так можно увидеть какие стили отрабатывают на iPhone и понять в чем конкретно проблема. Видит ли телефон вообще нужные стили или это просто кеш. (Кстати, если тестите на iPhone то действительно попробуйте с приватной вкладки зайти на страницу).

Comment: Дело в том, что работаю на винде. В приватной вкладке все отлично работает, в чем же проблема тогда? Проверил на iPhone 5s, на нем все отлично без приватной вкладки. Проблема на моем 6s только.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сбросьте кеш или подождите когда протухнут закешированные стили ;) Чтобы принудительно заставить все браузеры скачать новую версию стилей — добавьте к месту подключения файлы стилей GET запрос. Т.е. будет что-то вроде:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css?v=1">
```

Можно при каждом глобальном изменении стилей сделать обновление номера версии с 1 и далее. Для удобства разработки у нас была написана php'шная функция для генерации случайной строки при каждом обновлении окна:

```
...css?v=<?php echo generateRandomString(6);?>
```

Сам метод `generateRandomString` можно добавить в function.php

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Не забудьте потом для продакшна убрать этот хвост со стилей, и поставить просто номер версии, иначе каждый раз при обновлении страницы будут заново стили скачиваться, что замедлит серфинг по сайту.

Comment: Супер, помогло, спасибо :)